# SQL - sort of SUM with varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

have a (weird) table looking like this

```
ID    Version   Value1    Value2    Value3
1     1         Shaft     
1     2                   steel     xy
2     1                   Knife     somethins
2     3         Super
```

Want to merge, need to have this result, by using Value from the highest Version, that has content:

```
ID    Value1    Value2    Value3
1     Shaft     steel     xy
2     Super     Knife     somethin
```

as far as I know Group using Max(Version) would bring the NULL values of highest Version row.

something like SUM?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: which dbms do you use? it could be DB scpecific? Please add appropriate tag

Comment: MS SQL, query in MS SQL Studio

Comment: Have you tried any of the offered solutions? Do they meet/not meet your requirement? You've not offered a lot of feedback on this question via comments, etc.

Comment: Hi, I marked the Responses that worked for me using the "up and down" Buttons on the side. Good solution for me. Thx. Volker

Answer (score 1):

Second try... There are probably shorter and nicer solutions, but it should work:

```
with
v1 as 
(
select w1.id, w1.value1 from weird w1
where w1.value1 is not null
and w1.version=(select max(w11.version) from weird w11 where w11.id=w1.id and w11.value1 is not null) 
),
v2 as 
(
select w2.id, w2.value2 from weird w2
where w2.value2 is not null
and w2.version=(select max(w22.version) from weird w22 where w22.id=w2.id and w22.value2 is not null) 
),
v3 as 
(
select w3.id, w3.value3 from weird w3
where w3.value3 is not null
and w3.version=(select max(w33.version) from weird w33 where w33.id=w3.id and w33.value3 is not null) 
)
select v1.id, v1.value1, v2.value2, v3.value3
from v1, v2, v3
where v1.id=v2.id and v1.id=v3.id;
```

Comment: there is no `group by id`) but I like the logic)

Comment: Thank you! :-) I skipped the `group by id` becuase v* sub-selects should contain only one row per id in case ID/VERSION is a primary key.

Comment: it's not correct. Imagine you have multiple ids and for each id your need own version. In your case id is not even used. It should return as many rows as many ids you have

Comment: Sorry, I do not get this. V1, V2 and V3 contains as many rows, as many IDs I have, because for each ID the row with the maximum VERSION is selected. The main SELECT itself will also have this amount of resulting rows.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) creatively to construct the data you want:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, Version int not null, Value1 varchar(20) null,
                  Value2 varchar(20) null, Value3 varchar(20) null)
insert into @t(ID,Version,Value1,Value2,Value3) values
(1,1,'Shaft',null,null),
(1,2,null,'steel','xy'),
(2,1,null,'Knife','somethins'),
(2,3,'Super',null,null)

;With Numberable as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,Val ORDER BY Version desc) rn
    from @t t
    unpivot (tdata for Val in (Value1,Value2,Value3)) u
), Selected as (
    select ID,tdata,Val
    from Numberable where rn = 1
)
select
    *
from Selected s
pivot (MAX(tdata) for Val in (Value1,Value2,Value3)) u
```

The `UNPIVOT` automatically removes the `NULL`s. The `ROW_NUMBER()` identifies the values we want to keep. The `Selected` CTE hides the columns we no longer need so that the `PIVOT` creates the final result we want:

```
ID          Value1               Value2               Value3
----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           Shaft                steel                xy
2           Super                Knife                somethins
```

(I'm using `MAX` in the pivot but that's just to satisfy the optimizer. Because we've only selected one row for each `ID`, `Val` combination, we know that at most one value will be selected to appear in a final position in the grid formed by the pivot)

---

The above does make the assumption that `Value1`,`Value2` and `Value3` all have the same, or at least compatible, data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can rank the values with `row_number`. The following query first builds such ranks. `rn1` is built per `id` and `value1 is null`/`not null` in the descending order of the version. So per ID we get #1 for the last null value and the last filled value. Later we use `rn1 = 1` to get the maximum of the two, which is the last filled value. Same for `rn2`/`value2` and `rn3`/`value3`.

```
select 
  id,
  min(case when rn1 = 1 then value1 end) as value1,
  min(case when rn2 = 1 then value2 end) as value2,
  min(case when rn3 = 1 then value3 end) as value3
from
(
  select 
    id, value1, value2, value3,
    row_number() over (partition by id, case when value1 is null then 0 else 1 end order by version desc) as rn1,
    row_number() over (partition by id, case when value2 is null then 0 else 1 end order by version desc) as rn2,
    row_number() over (partition by id, case when value3 is null then 0 else 1 end order by version desc) as rn3
  from mytable
) ranked
group by id
order by id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Used `CASE WHEN` to `SELECT max(version)` where value is `not null` and `not blank` and then `joined`with the original table on those versions. You can see it in action in link provided below the query

Use this query.

```
Select distinct a.*, b.value1, c.value2, d.value3
from
(
Select id, max(case when (value1 is not null and value1 <> ' ') then version else 0 end) as ver1,
max(case when (value2 is not null and value2 <> ' ') then version else 0 end) as ver2,
max(case when (value3 is not null and value3 <> ' ') then version else 0 end) as ver3
from
your_table
group by id
) a
inner join
your_table b,
your_table c,
your_table d
where (a.ver1=b.version and a.id=b.id)
and (a.ver2=c.version and a.id=c.id)
and (a.ver3=d.version and a.id=d.id)
```

See it in action here at this [link](http://rextester.com/QUYCZ11428)

Comment: should be not just max but max by version

Comment: yeah.  That's why i wrote 'instead of max(version), OP can use max(value)', If OP feels this is easier to write and understand

Comment: This SELECT will not return any row for the example above. Which of the rows in the example table fulfills `where value1 is not null and value2 is not null and value3 is not null` ?

Comment: @Galcoholic This condition is not required. Check the link below the query to see it in action. But even if you keep it, it will not have any bearing on the results. Results will still be the same. Was testing something else earlier, forgot to remove that condition from the code

Comment: OK, but you used ' ' instead of NULLs. If you fix these values by setting to NULL your select will fail.

Comment: Check the questions. It has blanks and not nulls

Comment: I suggest you check the question: 1.: _" ...from the highest Version..."_ Where is it in your SELECT? 2. _"...that has content...  bring the NULL values ..."_ Has content means NOT NULL.

Comment: @Volker See updated query. I hope this is what you wanted.